# Navigating from day to day with Fullcalendar using a resource type resourceTimeline

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I use the Fullcalendar plugin. I would like to know if it is possible to navigate from day to day instead of 3 days to 3 days using the resourceTimeline view type with a duration of 3 days.

Thanks

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: 'fr',
    height: '95%',
    timeZone: 'Europe/Paris',
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    views: {
        resourceTimelineDay: {
            buttonText: 'Calendrier',
            titleFormat: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', weekday: 'long'}
        },
        listDay: {
            buttonText: 'Liste',
            titleFormat: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', weekday: 'long'}
        },
        resourceTimelineTenDay: {
            type: 'resourceTimeline',
            duration: { days: 3 },

            buttonText: '3 days'
        }
    },                      
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
    headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineDay,listDay,resourceTimelineTenDay'
    },
    validRange: {
        start: data.jourMin,
        end: data.jourMax
    },
    slotMinTime: '08:00:00',
    slotMaxTime: '24:00:00',
    slotMinWidth: 38,
    selectable: true,
    editable: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
    slotDuration: data.dureeSlot,
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Lieux',
    resources: './assets/json/salles.php',
    events: './assets/json/events.php',
    resourceAreaWidth: "10%",
    resourceOrder: 'title'
});
```

EDIT : I've tried using visibleRange but it doesn't do what I want. I followed the documentation to add this code in my custom view

```
visibleRange: function(currentDate) {
        // Generate a new date for manipulating in the next step
        var startDate = new Date(currentDate.valueOf());
        var endDate = new Date(currentDate.valueOf());

        // Adjust the start & end dates, respectively
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1); // One day in the past
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 2); // Two days into the future

        return { start: startDate, end: endDate };
      }
```

Comment: I think you'd have to dynamically set https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange (via its provided callback function, as seen in the documentation) rather than having a fixed duration for your custom view.

Comment: P.S. `resourceTimelineTenDay` doesn't make much sense as a title for a view with a 3-day duration?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My schedule must be displayed over a defined period, which is 10 days. I want to display only 3 days on the screen and navigate from day to day. 
For example: display a schedule from September 20 to 29. I display from 20th to 22nd, and when I click on the right arrow, I should be able to display from 21st to 23rd, but I'm currently going directly from 23rd to 25th.

Comment: Ok. Like I said then, you should explore using visibleRange to dynamically set the visible dates, rather than relying on a fixed `duration` setting

Comment: P.S. `My schedule must be displayed over a defined period, which is 10 days. I want to display only 3 days on the screen` sounds like a contradiction to me. Either you want to display 10 days, or you want to display 3 days. But it's not really relevant to your question particularly.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't seen the first answer. I want to display only 3 days on screen but the user can browse over a period of 10 days

Comment: Well if you want to limit the range of dates between which they can navigate, the `validRange` option should help you - it looks like you're already using that

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can do this very easily with the [`dayCount`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayCount) option, which guarantees a set number of days will appear in your view, but doesn't set a `duration`, meaning that the navigation buttons cause it to advance one day at a time:

```
  resourceTimelineTenDay: {
    type: "resourceTimeline",
    buttonText: "3 days",
    dayCount: 3,
  }
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzgxBYe